# for /f "tokens*" %%a in (echo variable>>anotherfile.csv) do (2>>failprotocol.log)

Tags: batch-file

I'm actually pretty much stuck in a problem I somehow can't solve:
I have made a ping that does ping to a Server every second and it writes it into a CSV-File.

The Problem is: When the file is opened, it cant be accessed and there will be no data written into my file.

I try to extract the Error "The process cannot access to the file..." to send the data into a another file.

```
for /f "tokens*" %%a in ('echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv') do (2>>%TEMP%\Dauerfail.log)
```

I tried to get any Errorlevel of the "The process...", but it doensn't send any. It keeps the standarderrorlevel of 1.

```
echo %errorlevel%>>dauerping.csv 2>Nul
```

The .csv-File was open so it got the Error that the process couldn't access to the file and so on... , but the Errorlevel stayed the same as before and the Error was still shown and not sent to nirvana.

Is there  any way to get my Batchfile to see this error and send my data into the other .csv-file to reduce informationloss?
And is there any way to get those ">>" into the for loop as an "in-expression"?

Thank u very much for your help!

The full code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
chcp 1252>nul
set ue=ü
set ae=ä
set oe=ö
set Uue=Ü
set Aae=Ä
set Ooe=Ö
set ss=ß
chcp 850>nul
del %TEMP%\Dauerping.log /s /q>Nul 2>Nul
del %TEMP%\Dauertime.log /s /q>Nul 2>nul
del %TEMP%\Dauerfail.log /s /q>Nul 2>nul
echo Dauerping l%ae%uft!
set srv=srv-file-02
:Schleife
ping -n 1 %srv% | find "Antwort von" >>%TEMP%\Dauerping.log
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('ping -n 1 %srv%') do set fehler=%%i
set fail=0
echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% >>%TEMP%\Dauertime.log
FOR /f "tokens=1,3,4,5 " %%f  IN (%TEMP%\Dauerping.log) DO set late=%%i
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN (%TEMP%\Dauertime.log) DO set t=%%a %%b
set t2=%t:~0,10%
set t3=%t:~11,19%
set late2=%late:~5,9%
echo %fehler%|findstr "nicht finden">nul && set fail=1
if %fail%==1 echo Fehler && set late2=Fehler
echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv
for /f "tokens*" %%a in ('echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv') do (2>>%TEMP%\Dauerfail.log)
Pause>Nul
if %errorlevel%==1 echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerpingproc.csv
waitfor test /t:1 2>Nul 1>Nul
GOTO Schleife
```

Working script:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252>nul
set ue=ü
set ae=ä
set oe=ö
set Uue=Ü
set Aae=Ä
set Ooe=Ö
set ss=ß
chcp 850>nul
del %TEMP%\Dauerping.log /s /q>Nul 2>Nul
del %TEMP%\Dauertime.log /s /q>Nul 2>nul
echo Dauerping l%ae%uft!
set srv=srv-file-02
:Schleife
ping -n 1 %srv% | find "Antwort von" >>%TEMP%\Dauerping.log
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('ping -n 1 %srv%') do set fehler=%%i
set fail=0
set fail2=0
echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% >>%TEMP%\Dauertime.log
FOR /f "tokens=1,3,4,5 " %%f  IN (%TEMP%\Dauerping.log) DO set late=%%i
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN (%TEMP%\Dauertime.log) DO set t=%%a %%b
set t2=%t:~0,10%
set t3=%t:~11,19%
set late2=%late:~5,9%
echo %fehler%|findstr "nicht finden">nul && set fail=1
if %fail%==1 echo Fehler && set late2=Fehler
echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerpingproc.csv
waitfor test /t:1 2>Nul 1>Nul
GOTO Schleife
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in lines 30-32. It is incorrect but I cannot work out your intention. What is supposed to be written to Dauerping.csv, Dauerfail.log and Dauerpingproc.csv?

Comment: I try to have in the Dauerping.csv the data of date;time;latency or if it fails.
The dauerfail.log was just a temporary file for maybe storing the error, when it occures when the file is opened.

In the Dauerpingproc.csv should go the Information from Dauerping.csv, while the origninal file isnt accessable.

My essential problem is/was to find the right way to indicate the error and then send the data to the file.


I actually know that this script above doesnt work properly, but i wanted it as an example for the errorcatching.

Comment: This is the important part:`for /f "tokens*" %%a in ('echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv') do (2>>%TEMP%\Dauerfail.log)`

Comment: If you delete this part:
`for /f "tokens*" %%a in ('echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv') do (2>>%TEMP%\Dauerfail.log)
Pause>Nul
if %errorlevel%==1 echo %t2%;%t3%;%late2%>>%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerpingproc.csv`

then it should be working

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guess at what I think your script is supposed to do:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal

>nul chcp 1252
set ae=ä
>nul chcp 850

echo Dauerping l%ae%uft!

set "srv=srv-file-02"

:Schleife
set "late="
for /f "tokens=7 delims== " %%a in (
    'ping -n 1 %srv% ^|find "TTL"') do set "late=%%a"
if not defined late (set "late=Fehler" & echo Fehler)
>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv" (
    echo %date%;%time:~,8%;%late%) 2>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerpingproc.csv"
waitfor test /t:1 2>Nul 1>&2
goto :Schleife
```

Apologies if it is incorrect, but I hope it helps you find a solution.

If that isn't your intention for the output,  perhaps this is:

```bat
:Schleife
set "late="
for /f "tokens=7 delims== " %%a in (
    'ping -n 1 %srv% ^|find "TTL"') do set "late=%%a"
if not defined late (set "late=Fehler" & echo Fehler)
echo %date%;%time:~,8%;%late% >>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerping.csv" 2>nul|| (
    echo %date%;%time:~,8%;%late% >>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dauerpingproc.csv")
waitfor test /t:1 2>Nul 1>&2
goto :Schleife
```

Comment: Sorry but your script runs by me all the time into the error "the command late has not been found"

Are you actually writing the latency into the file?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Thanks for fixing, but it records only errors ("Fehler"). Even with my localhost. 

Have u ran my script without the 3 colomns of code i mentioned above? Thats how the file should look like in the end :). Your script is pretty good not using so many temporary files unlike mine.

Comment: I can't test it, firstly I'm not using Windows and secondly I'm not German. If you provide me with the output of `ping -n 1 localhost|find "TTL"` I may be able to debug

Comment: ERROR found, try it again!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past but I pasted the raw data into a txt file, and then was able to filter the content into whatever file formatted I wanted. the txt file will always be updated even if you have it open and you could tell the batch file to wait every x amount of time then filter the raw data into the csv file.

I know this isn't what you're looking for but might be a work around.
-Kind regards